# How to use the derived column and column pattern in adf to divide multiple columns by 4?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

How to use the derived column and column pattern in adf to divide multiple columns by 4?

I have multiple columns that start with the characters: 'test'

All these columns have to be divided by 4. I want to use the 'Add column pattern' method in the derived column in the data flow of Azure data factory.

[image]

Anything would help!

Comment: Do you want the results to replace the original column or create new columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my sample input data:

[image]

If you want the result columns to replace the original columns, use the column pattern like below.

Condition:

```
startsWith(name,'test')
```

Use `$$` in the expression.

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

If you want to create new columns for every column that matches our condition, give `$$+'<any name>'` or `<any name>+$$`.

[image]

**Result:**

[image]